# How do I export a jar as a RELEASE and not as a SNAPSHOT in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft

I'm currently working on a project and to test it, it double-click the package button (maven section, right) to export it as a jar, so I can test it on my server (Minecraft Plugin Development). Now, every time IntelliJ exports a jar, there's this suffix 'SNAPSHOT'. How do I change it to 'RELEASE'? Since other developers also use IntelliJ and dont change it manually. Anyone knows where I can change it in the settings? And yes, I am using Maven.

Comment: Check your pom file buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` to `<version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>` in your pom.xml